# Where can I get the BIP39 file?

Tags: bip39, seed-phrase

I would like to leave a copy of the BIP39 words with a person of my trust.

Where is the safest place I can download the BIP39 file?

Answer (score 7):

The [list of the word lists is included](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/bip-0039-wordlists.md) in BIP39, this is used directly in Yoroi as part of the [BIP39 JavaScript module](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip39/blob/d8ea080a18b40f301d4e2219a2991cd2417e83c2/util/wordlists.js#L37).

It appears, Daedalus is using [its own wordlist](https://github.com/input-output-hk/daedalus/blob/develop/source/common/config/crypto/valid-words.en.js).

Comment: The Daedalus wordlist is defined in a different place, but that seems unrelated to the wordlist itself. They're both 2048 words and, on inspection, look identical.

Answer (score 1):

**Having digital copies of your mnemonic set is always discouraged due to security issues.**

However, if you really want to give a digital copy of your recovery phrase to a person I'd personally suggest to take a picture of the recovery phrase, encrypt the picture, compress the encrypted picture and finally encrypt the compressed file again.

Please take this suggestion with caution since I'm not a security expert.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! It's in IOG's `cardano-crypto` repository. Have a look:

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-crypto/blob/develop/src/Crypto/Encoding/BIP39/English.hs

Answer (score 0):

You can download this website to a folder https://iancoleman.io/bip39/
and generate a BIP39 code on a clean computer not connected to the internet.

With that site, you can generate as much as you want.
or just buy a nano ledger x. Far easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [*BIP39 english wordlist*](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt) and a detailed [***instruction***](https://medium.com/geekculture/cryptocurrency-911-how-does-12-word-seed-phrase-work-9d892de9732) how to generate a seed phrase from it.

You can store BIP39-wordlist anywhere you like. But the ***seed phrase*** generated with these 2048 words should be kept away from strangers.